# Refactor nested foreach statements

Tags: c#

I've got a *nested* `foreach` statement which is successfully doing what I want to do. The only problem is, it *looks messy*. How can I refactor the code to make it more readable and clean?

```
List<int> dofm = new List<int>();

var dayOfMonth = Convert.ToString(ut.dayOfMonth);

dofm = dayOfMonth
  .Split(',')
  .Select(s => {
     int.TryParse(s, out int i);
     return i - 1; })
  .ToList();

foreach (var a in model.Schedule.DofMInfo)
{
    foreach (var b in dofm)
    {
        if (a.DofMID.Equals(b))
        {
            a.IsChecked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can start using more meaningful variables names.

Comment: Writing code in less lines and making your code more readable aren't always overlapping goals.  It depends on who's doing the reading.  Advanced programmers are often able to one-line their code by employing advanced or rarely-used language features that make it less readable, not more, to more novice programmers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Join`:

```
var items = model.Schedule.DofMInfo
    .Join(dofm, dmi => dmi.DofMID, d => d, (dmi, d) => dmi);

foreach (var item in items)
{
    item.IsChecked = true;
}
```

Comment: You're not joining on the correct thing.  It should be `dmi => dmi.DofMID`  Also you're missing a dot before `Join`.

Comment: @juharr Right, these names are too messy to handle it...

Answer (score 2):

I suggest something like this:

```
// HashSet is faster than List<T> on Contains: O(1) vs. O(N)
HashSet<int> dofm = new HashSet<int>(dayOfMonth
  .Split(',')
  .Select(s => int.TryParse(s, out int i) ? i - 1 : -1));

// Second loop can be changed into "Contains"
foreach(var a in model.Schedule.DofMInfo)
  if (dofm.Contains(a.DofMID))
    a.IsChecked = true;
```